# How can I get all sum of data from arraylist in a for loop?

Tags: java

This is the code:

```
ArrayList<DailyChallengesModelFinal> dailyList = new ArrayList<>();
    int selectedItems = position;
                    Log.d("dbKEY", String.valueOf(exDBKey));
                    int sum = 0;
                    for (int i = selectedItems; i <=0; i++) {


                        int points = dailyList.get(position).getPoints();
                        sum = sum + points;     }
```

I'm not getting the desired result.

What I wanna get is for example the array has 50,80,and 60 then it should add the values from the array.

Comment: please put here full code so we can see give you ansewer.

Comment: @mjwills it's an int

Comment: initial `position ` value ?

Comment: @Basi it's zero

Comment: @AndroidGirl then what is this `i <=0` looping to `<0` by incrementing `i` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
  int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <=dailyList.size(); i++) {
        dailyExerciseID = dailyList.get(i).getDcExerciseId();
        dailyExerciseName = dailyList.get(i).getDcexerciseName();
        points = dailyList.get(i).getPoints();
        sum = sum + points;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
for (int i = selectedItems; i <=0; i++) {
```

The starting value of `i` is `selectedItems` which is a positive number I suppose. 
The limit you set for the loop to stop is `i <=0` while you increase `i` by `i++`.
This for loop will never execute.
Change the starting point and the condition to stop.
If you want to iterate through the whole list then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dailyList.size(); i++) {
```

If you want to iterate through the first `selectedItems` items then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do your job:

```
    ArrayList<DailyChallengesModelFinal> dailyList = new ArrayList<>();
    int selectedItems = position;
                    Log.d("dbKEY", String.valueOf(exDBKey));
                    int sum = 0;
                    for (int i = selectedItems; i > 0; i--) 
                    {
                        int points = dailyList.get(i).getPoints();
                        sum += points;     
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dailyList.subList(position, dailyList.size()).stream().map(DailyChallengesModelFinal::getPoint).reduce((p1, p2) -> p1 + p2).orElse(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have updated your code. Please check it.

```
               int sum = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i <dailyList.size(); i++) {

                dailyExerciseID = dailyList.get(position).getDcExerciseId();
                dailyExerciseName = dailyList.get(position).getDcexerciseName();
                sum = sum + dailyList.get(position).getPoints();

              }
```

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: I have edited the description, please try to look at it.

Comment: give reason for downvoting.